# heroku deploy anomaly for play framework 2.2

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.2

My application is having a weird behaviour on heroku. Recently I've noticed that the application in production is out of date with my last push to heroku.

I've tried making a few minor changes and none of them are visible.

```
git push heroku master
```

results in no error

I've loged in ssh to heroku (heroku run bash) and all the files are up to date with my local machine. The only error I've been able to get is if, while on ssh, I run:

```
sbt clean compile stage
```

I get the following output

```
~ $ sbt clean compile stage                      

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true                                           
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt_2.9.1 0.11.3 ...                                                                     
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.11.3/jars/sbt_2.9.1.jar ...                                                                                                          
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3!sbt_2.9.1.jar (141ms)                                     
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/main_2.9.1/0.11.3/jars/main_2.9.1.jar ...                                                                                                        
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main_2.9.1;0.11.3!main_2.9.1.jar (435ms)                                   
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/ivy-typesafe-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.11.3/jars/compiler-interface-src.jar ...                                                                                    
        ...........................................
        ............edited.........................
        ...........................................

        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache_2.9.1;0.11.3!cache_2.9.1.jar (238ms)
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-tools/testing/test-interface/0.5/test-interface-0.5.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5!test-interface.jar (130ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        37 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (7245kB/67ms)
Getting Scala 2.9.1 (for sbt)...
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.9.1/scala-compiler-2.9.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.9.1!scala-compiler.jar (1093ms)
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.1/scala-library-2.9.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1!scala-library.jar (1142ms)
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/scala-lang/jline/2.9.1/jline-2.9.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.9.1!jline.jar (192ms)
downloading http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.4/jansi-1.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4!jansi.jar (104ms)
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        4 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (19939kB/44ms)
[info] Loading global plugins from /app/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/app/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins/}default-0f55ac...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.11.3 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main_2.9.1;0.11.3 ...
        ...........................................
        ............edited.........................
        ...........................................

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.11.3 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /app/.sbt_home/.sbt/plugins/target/scala-2.9.1/sbt-0.11.3/classes...
[info] Loading project definition from /app/project
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /app/.sbt_home/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.2.3/sbt-plugin-2.2.3.pom
[warn] ==== heroku-sbt-typesafe: tried
[warn] ==== heroku-central: tried
[warn]   http://s3pository.heroku.com/maven-central/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.2.3/sbt-plugin-2.2.3.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.3/2.2.3/sbt-plugin-2.2.3.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.2.3 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/app/project/}default-525df6/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.3: not found
```

plugin.sbt is

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.3")
```

and build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

Any ideas?

---

Changed sbt.version to 0.13.5 and changed a view.
This is the output of git push heroku master:

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 611 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Play 2.x - Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
-----> Running: sbt compile stage
       Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.5/jars/sbt.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.5!sbt.jar (94ms)
       downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.4/scala-library-2.10.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4!scala-library.jar (2067ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.5/jars/main.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.5!main.jar (239ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.5/jars/compiler-interface-src.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.5!compiler-interface-src.jar (93ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.5/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.5!compiler-interface-bin.jar (413ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.5/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.5!compiler-interface-bin.jar (386ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.5/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.5!compiler-interface-bin.jar (458ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.5/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.5!compiler-interface-bin.jar (488ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.5/jars/actions.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.5!actions.jar (372ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.5/jars/main-settings.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.5!main-settings.jar (181ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/interface/0.13.5/jars/interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.5!interface.jar (371ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.5/jars/io.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.5!io.jar (128ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.5/jars/ivy.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.5!ivy.jar (177ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/launcher-interface/0.13.5/jars/launcher-interface.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#launcher-interface;0.13.5!launcher-interface.jar (236ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logging/0.13.5/jars/logging.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logging;0.13.5!logging.jar (351ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/logic/0.13.5/jars/logic.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.5!logic.jar (350ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/process/0.13.5/jars/process.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#process;0.13.5!process.jar (367ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/run/0.13.5/jars/run.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.5!run.jar (258ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.5/jars/command.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.5!command.jar (541ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classpath/0.13.5/jars/classpath.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classpath;0.13.5!classpath.jar (511ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.5/jars/completion.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.5!completion.jar (96ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.5/jars/api.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.5!api.jar (81ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-integration/0.13.5/jars/compiler-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-integration;0.13.5!compiler-integration.jar (396ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-ivy-integration/0.13.5/jars/compiler-ivy-integration.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-ivy-integration;0.13.5!compiler-ivy-integration.jar (1157ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/relation/0.13.5/jars/relation.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#relation;0.13.5!relation.jar (74ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/task-system/0.13.5/jars/task-system.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.5!task-system.jar (103ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tasks/0.13.5/jars/tasks.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.5!tasks.jar (79ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/tracking/0.13.5/jars/tracking.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.5!tracking.jar (438ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/testing/0.13.5/jars/testing.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.5!testing.jar (77ms)
       downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.4/scala-compiler-2.10.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4!scala-compiler.jar (1150ms)
       downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.4/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4!scala-reflect.jar (635ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/control/0.13.5/jars/control.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#control;0.13.5!control.jar (421ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.5/jars/collections.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.5!collections.jar (157ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.5/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.5!incremental-compiler.jar (371ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.5/jars/compile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.5!compile.jar (104ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/persist/0.13.5/jars/persist.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#persist;0.13.5!persist.jar (129ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/classfile/0.13.5/jars/classfile.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#classfile;0.13.5!classfile.jar (430ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cross/0.13.5/jars/cross.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cross;0.13.5!cross.jar (515ms)
       downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.3.0!ivy.jar (557ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/cache/0.13.5/jars/cache.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.5!cache.jar (334ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/test-agent/0.13.5/jars/test-agent.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.5!test-agent.jar (254ms)
       downloading http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/apply-macro/0.13.5/jars/apply-macro.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.5!apply-macro.jar (106ms)
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        44 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (13482kB/335ms)
       Getting Scala 2.10.4 (for sbt)...
       downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/jline/2.10.4/jline-2.10.4.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4!jline.jar (384ms)
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24459kB/131ms)
       [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project
       [info] Set current project to gifwithsauce (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
       [info] Updating {file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/}scala_buildpack_build_dir...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.0-GA ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#templates_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-file_2.10;0.4.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-core_2.10;0.4.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.jsuereth#scala-arm_2.10;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;0.7 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.3.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.3 ...
       [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.7.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.13 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.2.0 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.10;2.2.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.7.18 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
       [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
       [info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;14.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.172 ...
       [info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.12 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-validator;5.0.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving javax.validation#validation-api;1.1.0.Final ...
       [info] Resolving org.jboss.logging#jboss-logging;3.1.1.GA ...
       [info] Resolving com.fasterxml#classmate;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-context;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-core;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-beans;3.2.3.RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving org.reflections#reflections;0.9.8 ...
       [info] Resolving dom4j#dom4j;1.6.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving javax.servlet#javax.servlet-api;3.0.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ebean_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm;3.2.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.avaje.ebeanorm#avaje-ebeanorm-agent;3.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Final ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webjars#webjars-play_2.10;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webjars#requirejs;2.1.8 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webjars#webjars-locator;0.6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webjars#bootstrap;2.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webjars#jquery;1.8.2 ...
       [info] Resolving postgresql#postgresql;9.1-901-1.jdbc4 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-lang#commons-lang;2.6 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
       [info] Resolving org.jsoup#jsoup;1.7.1 ...
       [info] Resolving com.github.slugify#slugify;1.0-RELEASE ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
       [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;2.1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
       [info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.10 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.8.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
       [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.12 ...
       [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
       [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
       [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.12 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.18 ...
       [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.9 ...
       [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
       [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.32.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
       [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.2.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.0 ...
       [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.10;1.0.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.0 ...
       [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
       [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;4.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;4.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;4.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;4.1 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3 ...
       [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
       [info] downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.1/httpclient-4.2.1-tests.jar ...
       [info]   [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar(test-jar) (362ms)
       [info] Done updating.
       [info] Compiling 19 Scala sources and 12 Java sources to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/classes...
       [info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3. Compiling...
       [info]   Compilation completed in 54.78 s
       [warn] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/conf/routes:15: unreachable code
       [warn] GET     /gif/:id/                   controllers.Application.index(id: Long,noSource: String ?= null,slug = null)
       [warn] one warning found
       [success] Total time: 113 s, completed Jul 24, 2014 7:23:10 PM
       [info] Wrote /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/gifwithsauce_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/gifwithsauce_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
       [info] Done packaging.
       [info] Main Scala API documentation to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/api...
       model contains 50 documentable templates
       [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/gifwithsauce_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
       [info] Done packaging.
       [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
       [info] Packaging /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/gifwithsauce_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
       [info] Done packaging.
       [success] Total time: 283 s, completed Jul 24, 2014 7:27:53 PM
-----> Dropping ivy cache from the slug
-----> Dropping project boot dir from the slug
-----> Dropping compilation artifacts from the slug
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 149.9MB
-----> Launching... done, v124
-----> Deploy hooks scheduled, check output in your logs
       http://gifwithsauce.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku  
       *(WARNING NSFW URL)*

To git@heroku.com:gifwithsauce.git
   a4ff64c..a291a12  master -> master
```

It looks like everything is fine, but the view was not updated...

Answer (score 0):

Try using sbt.version=0.13.5 - It was recently [announced](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/483)

It also looks like it is using Scala 2.9.1 and sbt 0.11.3

Is there a chance you have an old Build.scala of some sort?

Perhaps the problem is with the warning? How do you make sure it's not updated?

```
   [warn] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/conf/routes:15: unreachable code
   [warn] GET     /gif/:id/                   controllers.Application.index(id: Long,noSource: String ?= null,slug = null)
   [warn] one warning found
```

Comment: I tried with 0.13.5 but gave the exact same output/error, and there isn't a Build.scala file in /project

Comment: can you please provide the output after you call git push heroku master? you are not suppose to call sbt compile on your dyno. The "compiling" stage of Heroku takes care for it and prepares a slug that you only need to run.

Comment: I've added it, it looks fine, but the application did not get updated

Comment: I fixed the warning modifiyng the routes file, but still nothing. I've added html comments on a view and changed a bit the code of a controller and neither of this changes are visible in the html source. In development, both changes are reflected

Comment: perhaps you should fork (clone) to another heroku app to make sure you are experiencing an old slug and not a bad deployment cycle